# Scala, Spring, WebFlow, Hibernate and Maven or Java, Spring, WebFlow, Hibernate and Maven

Tags: java, spring, scala, maven, jboss

I been writing a number of systems in Java, Spring, WebFlow, Hibernate and Maven running them on JBoss servers. I am thinking about learning Scala..

is anyone using Scala, Spring, WebFlow, Hibernate and Maven for real life projects running in big firms??

should I move to Scala, Spring, WebFlow, Hibernate and Maven?

Comment: Maybe a "Programmers" question? However I find it interesting...

Comment: Some will say yes (scala is awesome), others will say no (if it works, why bother?). It is hard to answer such question without polling and debate. Voted for closing. By the way Scala community tends to use SBT and mostly looks on Maven as on a step back.

Comment: @gd1, no, [questions like this are explicitly disallowed](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) on [Programmers.SE] (even more clearly than for SO itself - see the SO [FAQ]).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on the project. We use lots of Spring MVC (REST) + pure html/js UI. It is really reasonable. I think you better look some comparisons, like http://www.slideshare.net/mraible/comparing-jvm-web-frameworks-jfokus-2012 - they will give you much more information of what to use.

As for me, I'd never use WebFlow or JSF..